# sum of columns and list difference between rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the difference between rows based on group by SELL_ID on the below table,

table1 - (table formatting courtesy of [GitHub](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/))

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+
| seq_ID  | REQ_ID  | CALL_ID  | SELL_ID  |     REGION       |  COUNT  |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+
|    1    |    123  | C001     | S1       | AGL              |  510563 |
|    2    |    123  | C001     | S1       | USL              |  122967 |
|    3    |    123  | C001     | S1       | VALIC            |  614106 |
|    4    |    123  | C001     | S2       | Inforce          | 1247636 |
|    5    |    123  | C001     | S2       | NB               |       0 |
|    6    |    123  | C001     | S3       | Seriatim Summary | 1247636 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+------------------+---------+
```

I am trying to get the results as below,

table2 -

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
| seq_ID  | REQ_ID  | CALL_ID  | Summary  | COUNT |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
|    1    |    123  | C001     | S1_vs_S2 |     0 |
|    2    |    123  | C001     | S2_vs_S3 |     0 |
|    3    |    123  | C001     | S3_vs_s1 |     0 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+-------+
```

S1_vs_S2 is the difference between `(sum(count) from table1 where sell_id='S1')` and `(sum(count) from table1 where sell_id='S2')`

Below is the code that i am using, But couldn't fetch the results,

```
INSERT INTO table2 (SEQ_ID, REQ_ID,call_id,summary,count) 
SELECT min(seq_id) seq_id
     , req_id
     , call_id
     , S1_vs_S2
     ,((SELECT sum(c2) FROM TABLE_STG_CTRL WHERE source='S1')-
        SELECT sum(c2) FROM TABLE_STG_CTRL WHERE source='S2'))
FROM table1
GROUP BY req_ID, Ctrl_ID, c1, source 
ORDER BY SEQ_ID ;
```

Comment: Are the sell_id sequential like S1, S2, S3 etc

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
select req_id, call_id, sell_id,
       lead(sell_id) over (partition by req_id, call_id order by seq_id) as next_sell_id,
       (cnt -
        lead(cnt) over (partition by req_id, call_id order by seq_id)
       ) as diff
from (select req_id, call_id, sell_id, sum(count) as cnt, min(seq_id) as seq_id
      from t
      group by req_id, call_id, sell_id
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

At first group data on `sell_id, req_id, call_id`. This is subquery `t` in my code. Then self join properly this result and show difference. The only problem is to construct `join` condition carefully:

**<sup>[demo with your sample data](https://rextester.com/YEYKX46877)</sup>**

```
with t as (
  select sell_id sid, req_id, call_id, sum(cnt) cnt
    from table1 
    group by sell_id, req_id, call_id )
select case t1.sid when 'S1' then 1 when 'S2' then 2 when 'S3' then 3 end id, 
       t1.req_id, t1.call_id, t1.sid||'_vs_'||t2.sid call_id, t1.cnt - t2.cnt diff
  from t t1 
  join t t2 on t1.req_id = t2.req_id 
           and t1.call_id = t2.call_id 
           and (t1.sid, t2.sid) in (('S1', 'S2'), ('S2', 'S3'), ('S3', 'S1'))
  order by id
```

BTW `count` is Oracle reserved word, please avoid such names when naming columns etc.